# How can I get Tap2print sdk for android application

Tags: android

I have created the account onTap2print.I create new application and choose Target Platform: android ,It's showing a message  ***"Android SDK will soon be ready. 
Until then the connection to the service is done using a REST API. An e-mail will be sent to you with additional integration instruction***."

Is it possible to integrate Tap2Print in android application using sdk or rest api.If it is possible using rest api then what will be the step to integrate Tap2Print in android application.